# How to cleanup Excel.AppEvents AdviseSinks?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, vsto

SO I ran into a problem using the WorkbookOpen event when in an ole embedded scenario: its a well documented issue:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2008/10/18/com-interop-handling-events-has-side-effects/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcook/2008/10/30/iconnectionpoint-and-net-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-managed-event-sinks-part-1/

reading this blog post
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/04/11/excel-ole-embedding-errors-if-you-have-managed-add-in-sinking-application-events-in-excel-2/

I not only need an IConnectionSink but also call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on each workbook object passed as a parameter.

```
public class ExcelAppEventSink : Excel.AppEvents
{
... other functions ...

public void WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
  <-- operate on workbook -->
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Wb);
}

... other functions ...
}
```

But another blog post from microsoft posted 2 years later claims Marshal.ReleaseComObject is dangerous.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous/

since I just need to release the [RCWs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would it be safer in 2016 to call
[CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.cleanupunusedobjectsincurrentcontext(v=vs.100).aspx) at the end of the function call instead?

extra reading material:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2006/09/19/mixing-deterministic-and-non-deterministic-cleanup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this answer was really good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/349202/ Don't like to have to specify using for every COM object but other than that the code is pretty clean.